# Calculate nearest location Google Map Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I know how to find the distance between two location on android studio google map but how to calculate which distance is the nearest one compering with 3 or 4 found location?

```
   public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Route route : routes) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

        originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));
        destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).
                color(Color.BLUE).
                width(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
            polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

        polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
    }
}
```

Comment: is it solved or not?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the distance,you can calculate like this way

```
 private double caldistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
      double theta = lon1 - lon2;
      double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
       return (dist);
    }

   private double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
   private double rad2deg(double rad) {
      return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the distance for all found locations and having smallest distance will be the nearest location.

```
public double distance(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1,
        double lon2, double el1, double el2) {

    final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth

    Double latDistance = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    Double lonDistance = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    Double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))
            * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
    Double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double distance = R * c * 1000; // convert to meters

    double height = el1 - el2;

    distance = Math.pow(distance, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2);

    return Math.sqrt(distance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the nearest locations

Create two Locations like this:

```
    Location source = new Location("");
    Location destination = new Location("");

    source.setLatitude(src_lat);
    source.setLongitude(src_lng);
    destination.setLatitude(dest_lat);
    destination.setLongitude(dest_lng);

    if(source.distanceTo(destination)<3000){     // 3000 meters = 3 km
        // do something ...
    }
```